# How can i merge two flowfiles in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have two flow files with the same file name(let says sample.txt). Now i need to merge these two flow files into one single flow file, but i need the data of the first flow fine then i have to append the second flow file data, so the final flow file from the processor should contain the merged data, let say below are two flow files

firstflow file(sample.txt) :

```
AAA BBB
CCC DDD
```

second flow file(sample.txt) :

```
EEE FFF
```

After merging it should be like below :

```
AAA BBB
CCC DDD
EEE FFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the MergeContent processor?
Try this with these properties set to:

```
Correlation Attribute Name : filename
Minimum Number of Entries : 2
Delimiter Strategy : Text
Demarcator : (newline char), To type this press: shift-enter
```